# Can't get the changes made in GridView to save to database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, gridview

Here is my code to populate the `GridView`. I want to be able to make changes to each column in the view. What step am I missing to get the changes I made to save back to the SQL Database?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myConnection.Open(); 
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    string query = @"select EmployeeId[Employee], DateIn, cast (timein as time(0))     [TimeIn], dateout, cast(timeout as time(0))[Time Out], job , 
                     costcode from Data_TimeCards_T  WHERE     (EmployeeID LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%') or  (job LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')";
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, myConnection);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
    DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView();
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = dTable;
    dgView.DataSource = bSource;
    dAdapter.Update(dTable);
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: The code seem to be correct. Just make changes in your datatable/Gridview and call dAdapter.Update(table) method.

Comment: Thanks that pointed me in the right direction and I was able to resolve my issue